# Is criteria hidden in spoiler tags sufficient reason for explaining why an answer is wrong?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, spoilers

I know [Prime Hidden in Plain Site](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5555/hidden-in-plain-sight-find-the-prime) is already a topic for a few different discussions, but I have another interesting question regarding it. Is hiding rules for acceptable answers in spoiler tags appropriate or acceptable? I feel that answers should be considered valid if they meet all the **visible** requirements of the given question.

In dialogue back and forth between AE and BmyGuest on [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/5566/3922) BmyGuest states that the answer is wrong because of a rule that is hidden in a spoiler tag. Is this something that should be allowed in questions?

Don't get me wrong, I thought the question was unique and intriguing, but the way it was presented left some question that probably should be answered...

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a fully formed answer to this, but my gut feeling is **no**, simply because a spoiler tag semantically contains spoilers. If you're trying to solve a puzzle and think you have an answer (but aren't sure) you shouldn't have to read **spoilers** for information contained in them which you can use to verify your answer because it's just as likely that the **spoilers** contain... y'know, spoilers.